# Warning: the current language does not match this frame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, debugging

This shows up in the debugging console in Xcode. What does it mean and should I be concerned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It generally means that you're debugging ObjC++ and that gdb has gotten confused about what language you're in the middle of. gdb often has trouble in ObjC++, which is one of many reasons to keep your C++ and ObjC separate as much as you can. A related error is along the lines of "No `this` pointer."