# sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all Warning: the current language does not match this frame. Current language: auto; currently objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have Integrated Cocos2d to my Windows based application. When I run my Project I am getting the Crash after executing the line `CC_DIRECTOR_INIT();` The error is  **sharedlibrary **apply-load-rules all
Warning: the current language does not match this frame.
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c****. I found the meaning of the error form this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651661/warning-the-current-language-does-not-match-this-frame). But My question is how can I Implement this in my Project. I am new to cocos2-d. Any suggestions is appreciated.

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application
{
    CC_DIRECTOR_INIT();
    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
    [director setDisplayFPS:YES];
    EAGLView *view = [director openGLView];
    [view setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];    
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: [Helloworld scene]];
}
```

This is the Screenshot where the crash occurs...
 [image: This is the screenshot of where the crash occurs.]

EDIT:
MY Console output..

```
#0  0x0002e60f in -[CCLabelAtlas updateAtlasValues] (self=0x68224c0, _cmd=0xc0be2) at CCLabelAtlas.m:75
#1  0x0002e994 in -[CCLabelAtlas setString:] (self=0x68224c0, _cmd=0x310f12c, newString=0xf3b98) at CCLabelAtlas.m:113
#2  0x0002e49c in -[CCLabelAtlas initWithString:charMapFile:itemWidth:itemHeight:startCharMap:] (self=0x68224c0, _cmd=0xb8d31, theString=0xf3b98, charmapfile=0xf3b88, w=16, h=24, c=46 '.') at CCLabelAtlas.m:50
#3  0x0002e380 in +[CCLabelAtlas labelAtlasWithString:charMapFile:itemWidth:itemHeight:startCharMap:] (self=0xf1ebc, _cmd=0xb6fd5, string=0xf3b98, charmapfile=0xf3b88, w=16, h=24, c=46 '.') at CCLabelAtlas.m:40
#4  0x0001268a in -[CCDirector setGLDefaultValues] (self=0x681c300, _cmd=0xb6b3d) at CCDirector.m:219
#5  0x0001406d in -[CCDirector setOpenGLView:] (self=0x681c300, _cmd=0xb6a18, view=0x681c850) at CCDirector.m:549
#6  0x00002e58 in -[cocowindowAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] (self=0x681abe0, _cmd=0xd050a3, application=0x68016f0) at cocowindowAppDelegate.m:32
#7  0x00912ce2 in -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] ()
#8  0x00914d88 in -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] ()
#9  0x0091f617 in -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] ()
#10 0x00917abf in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
#11 0x0091cf2e in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#12 0x02e61992 in PurpleEventCallback ()
#13 0x01403944 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#14 0x01363cf7 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
#15 0x01360f83 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#16 0x01360840 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#17 0x01360761 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#18 0x009147d2 in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#19 0x00920c93 in UIApplicationMain ()
#20 0x00002b39 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffeff0) at main.m:14
(gdb)
```

Comment: Friends I found the answer to this question from this link..http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/8209... thanks to xoebus :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXC_ARITHMETIC` usually means that you are dividing by zero. If you look in your screenshot then you are evaluating:

```
int row = (a % itemsPerRow) //...
```

From the output of your debugger it looks like `itemsPerRow` is 0 when this is caused and so the program is crashing. Try initialising this value or setting some conditional code if it is meant to be zero to stop it dividing by zero.

The warning message `Warning: the current language does not match this frame.` is just GDB getting a bit confused as to what language it is meant to be debugging. As you can see, it manages to sort itself out on the next line.

**Edit:**

This poster has a similar error to you: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/8209 Does his fix apply to you?

Comment: @Kattu I'll have a look now but it looks like a value that should have been set before this method was invoked. This could possibly be by a setter or in the constructor of the class.

Comment: I have checked all.  CC_DIRECTOR_INIT(); is the first method to execute.

Comment: I had a quick look at the source of *Cocos2d* and it looks like the code that is crashing has been updated a bit since the version you're using. What version are you using and is it possible for you to update?

Comment: Does this similar solution help you? http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/8209

Comment: @xoebus let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1507/discussion-between-kattupoochi-and-xoebus)